# Rear brake cylinder's piston "really" stuck: how to remove it?

Tags: brakes, cylinder, seized-engine

The rear brakes in my hobby car are drums type. One of its brake cylinders have one of the pistons "really" stuck: it won't move by hydraulic force by pressing the brakes pedal; it won't move by slightly tapping it in or out of the cylinder body and didn't even moved after I caller the services of my Margarita (10 lbs hammer). It is really stuck...so what other thing I can try? Heat it? Freeze it? The body is cast iron, the piston is aluminum.

Comment: Hey bud! You aren't using your original account? It sounds like the piston is cocked in the calliper bore. Either that or rusted solid.

Comment: Mount it in a hydraulic press, if it breaks it needed replacing anyway... :)

Comment: @SolarMike - While I agree, the problem here is, Aram is in Cuba ... hard to get replacement car parts there. Very hard.

Comment: The thermal expansion coefficient of aluminum is about twice as big as steel. So if the piston is Al, freezing it would be better, if the body is also going to get cold. Heating the casing quickly, before the heat can soak through to the piston, might also work.

Comment: I totally forgot my original account :( anyway, I will try freezing the part and try to move it at least in, in a vice jaws. If it works, then I can move it enough to sand the cylinder walls and try again but outwards.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 How do I get the location from the detail in the question? So, if parts are not available, then perhaps making them becomes a necessity : the original meaning of the term “mechanic” involved making / machining - unlike the “fitters” that tend to be seen now. If it is that badly corroded then it may need boring and making oversize pistons. At least caliper pistons are relatively easy to machine...

Comment: @SolarMike - I'm wasn't dogging you out or giving you a hard time, I was just letting you know. Rebuilding a caliper seems like the best way to go in this case.

Comment: Dudes, it is not a caliper, it is a drum system´s cylinder. I have options although I would like to keep the original part. This is a Fiat 126P, from Poland. I know I can adapt a Lada brake cylinder...but my intention is to try keep the original, although this little thing has "many" adaptations.